# Nesting iteration - difference between for and while loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, iterator, python-itertools

I need to do a nested iteration over a generator (not a list).
What I need is to perform something like this:

```
testing  3 ...
Testing passed!
     Starting subtest:
     Sub-testing 4  with  3
     Sub-testing passed!
testing  4 ...
testing  5 ...
testing  6 ...
Testing passed!
     Starting subtest:
     Sub-testing 7  with  6
     Sub-testing 8  with  6
     Sub-testing 9  with  6
     Sub-testing passed!
testing  7 ...
testing  8 ...
testing  9 ...
Testing passed!
     Starting subtest:
     Sub-testing 10  with  9
     Sub-testing 11  with  9
     Sub-testing 12  with  9
     Sub-testing passed!
testing  10 ...
```

So I tried the following code , using a `for` loop:

```
from itertools import *
princ_iter = count(3)
for x in princ_iter:
    print("testing ", x, "...")
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print("Testing passed!")
        print("     Starting subtest:")
        princ_iter, nested_iter = tee(princ_iter)
        for y in nested_iter:
            print("     Sub-testing", y, " with ", x)
            if y % (x//2) == 0:
                print("     Sub-testing passed!")
                break
```

but it does not work because the principal iterator (`princ_iter`) is iterated together with the nested one (`nested_iter`) and I obtain this output instead:

```
testing  3 ...
Testing passed!
     Starting subtest:
     Sub-testing 4  with  3
     Sub-testing passed!
testing  5 ...
testing  6 ...
Testing passed!
     Starting subtest:
     Sub-testing 4  with  6
     Sub-testing 7  with  6
     Sub-testing 8  with  6
     Sub-testing 9  with  6
     Sub-testing passed!
testing  10 ...
testing  11 ...
```

So I tried using the same instructions in a `while` loop:

```
from itertools import *
princ_iter= count(3)
while True:
    x = next(princ_iter)
    print("testing ", x, "...")
...
```

and this time I have obtained exactly the output I was looking for !

Why there is this difference between the two instructions? Is there a (better) way to do it using a for loop?

Comment: Do not use `iter` or name of any other built-in function as a name of variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is behavior is alluded to in the documentations for [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

> Once `tee()` has made a split, the original `iterable` should not be used
> anywhere else; otherwise, the `iterable` could get advanced without the
> tee objects being informed.

When you use a for-loop, the *original iterator is being used the whole time*:

```
for x in princ_iter:
    ...
```

The for-loop will *always work with the same object*.

The fact that:

```
princ_iter, nested_iter = tee(princ_iter)
```

Re-assigns the `prince_iter` *variable* with a new iterator is irrelevant.

On the other hand, in your while-loop, this *is* relevant, because you are controlling what iterator is advanced:

```
x = next(princ_iter)
```

i.e., whatever iterator *is being currently referred to by `prince_iter`*, so the variable re-assignment *does* affect things.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something like this. So there is no way to perform it over a for loop?

Comment: @Ohibò is this the actual use-case? Like, you are using `itertools.count`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilaga No, this is just a toy example for explaining my point. In my case the iterator is of type `pdDataframe.iterrows()`. In any case I would like to see a valable solution for all iterators

Comment: @Ohibò yeah I can't think of a generic approach using a for-loop. As an aside, generally `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` should be avoided.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilaga I know, but I have a list of operations recorded in a dataframe, and for each operation I need to check which operations has been performed subsequently and do some calculations over them. So I do not figure how to do it without a loop